# Is there anything in containers that allows me to get a subset of Data.Set?

Tags: haskell, containers

I cannot find any functions that given a min and a max return all the values in that interval for any of the structures in containers. Surely there must be...?

Comment: maybe `Data.Set.filter`?  For example: `S.filter (\x -> 4 < x && x < 10) $ S.fromList [1..10]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
inRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> Set a -> Set a
inRange min max s = fst $ S.split max gt
  where (_, gt) = S.split min s
```

Comment: You could even do `fst . S.split max . snd . S.split min` and just use 1 line.

Comment: Perfect. I should have thought about using split like that!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the runtime of this?

Comment: @user3217013 [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:split) is O(lg n).  fst and snd are O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can write this really easily with `Data.Set.filter`:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

between :: Ord a => a -> a -> Set a -> Set a
between min_ max_ = S.filter (\x -> min_ <= x && x <= max_)
```

Then you can use it as

```
> between 3 7 $ S.fromList [1..10]
fromList [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: But given a large set, it is clearly far more efficient to query for the smallest key satisfying the bound, then walk the structure internally until hitting the highest key meeting the upper bound. If I only want a small subset that would save me visiting a large portion of the data structure, rather than the whole of it.

Comment: @benjumanji: Yes, `filter` is O(n), while using `split` gives you O(log n).

Comment: @benjumanji Then `split` will be a more efficient solution, but this will still work for small sets.